# Python: extract all the information(src, href, title) inside the class

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I found that I can extract all the information I want from this HTML. I need to extract title, href abd src from this.

HTML:

```
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 home-hot-thumb">
        <a itemprop="url" href="/slim?p=3090" class="main">
            <img src="/FileUploads/Post/3090.jpg?w=70&h=70&mode=crop" alt="apple" title="apple" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 home-hot-thumb">
        <a itemprop="url" href="/slim?p=3091" class="main">
            <img src="/FileUploads/Post/3091.jpg?w=70&h=70&mode=crop" alt="banana" title="banana" />
        </a>
    </div>
```

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('http://www.cad.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
for a in soup.findAll('div', {"id":"home"}):
    for b in a.select(".main"): 
        print ("http://www.cad.com"+b.get('href'))
        print(b.get('title'))
```

I can successfully get href from this, but since title and src are in another line, I don't know how to extract them. After this, I want to save them in excel, so maybe I need to finish one first then do the second one.

Expected output:

```
/slim?p=3090
apple
/FileUploads/Post/3091.jpg?w=70&h=70&mode=crop" alt="banana" title="banana
/slim?p=3091
banana
/FileUploads/Post/3091.jpg?w=70&h=70&mode=crop" alt="banana" title="banana
```

Answer (score 0):

My own solution:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('http://www.cad.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
for a in soup.findAll('div', {"id":"home"}):
    div = a.findAll('div', {"class": "home-hot-thumb"})
    for div in div:
        title=(div.img.get('title'))
        print(title)
        href=('http://www.cad.com/'+div.a.get('href'))
        print(href)
        src=('http://www.cad.com/'+div.img.get('src'))
        print(src.replace('?w=70&h=70&mode=crop', ''))
```